# Should we have a "Ratings" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think there should be a ratings tag for if people have a question on if a certain situation in their writing would tip them over an edge into another rating (Say, from PG to PG-13, or R to X?) Sorry for any confusion over ratings and stuff, if i could delete this, i would.

Comment: I just noticed (after answering) that your title says "tag" while your question says "tab".  I assumed you were proposing a UI change (a new tab on the front page).  Is that what you meant?  Could you [edit] to make them match, whichever you meant?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree that a [ratings](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratings) is required or tags for any specific rating value.

Given that the ratings mechanisms and the criteria that they apply are very different in different jurisdictions, I think it would be a very difficult tag to apply consistently.

The ratings you quote, R, X and PG-13, don't exist where I come from.  Here in the UK we have rating systems for cinema films, video games and websites - all of which are different and are policed by different organisations.  There are no ratings for books.

A question would have to specify the type of writing for which a rating is sought, and there are already tags for [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children), [screenplay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenplay) and others that would be applicable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

We don't get a lot of "R-rated and above" questions, so segregating them would probably mean they wouldn't get much attention -- people wouldn't be in the habit of going there.  Plus, the boundaries can be ambiguous sometimes, especially on a worldwide site with diverse cultural norms.  For example, in the US sex is considered "adult" but violence might only net an "adult supervision recommended" rating; in other parts of the world gun violence would be an instant "adult" but sex is more acceptable.

We do, however, have a mechanism to impede accidental viewing of material.  If in your question you need to talk about "adult" content, *however you define that*, you can use the "spoiler" formatting, like this:

> This is spoiler text.  It is only visible on hover.

To do that, begin your paragraph with `>!` (blockquote formatting + '!').

Comment: I noticed some people don't... Maybe they could have it out there? (unless it already is)